# sorting a datagrid with GWT

Tags: java, gwt, datagrid

I have a datagrid in GWT, and I'm using RPC to populate it with data, I can get the data to show up just fine, and I can also select individual cells but when it comes to sorting it just doesn't work! I can occasionaly click on column headers (it happens intermittently and I'm not sure why) but when I do nothing sorts. I'm using a dataProvider, but I think I'm implementing it incorrectly, I've attached the related code, can someone give me a pointer on how to do this correctly?

first is the actual table itself

```
public class GuiInventory {

public final static LayoutPanel hpMain = new LayoutPanel();

static ListHandler<OpInventory> sortHandler;
/*
* Define a key provider for a Contact. We use the unique ID as the key,
* which allows to maintain selection even if the name changes.
*/
static ProvidesKey<OpInventory> keyProvider = new ProvidesKey<OpInventory>() {
    @Override
    public Object getKey(OpInventory item) {
        // Always do a null check.
        return (item == null) ? null : item.getPartID();
    }
};

//the table
final static DataGrid<OpInventory> table = new DataGrid<OpInventory>(keyProvider);

final static SelectionModel<OpInventory> selectionModel = new MultiSelectionModel<OpInventory>(keyProvider);

/**
 * The provider that holds the list of contacts in the database.
 */
private final static ListDataProvider<OpInventory> dataProvider = new ListDataProvider<OpInventory>();

public ListDataProvider<OpInventory> getDataProvider() {
    return dataProvider;
}

/**
 * Add a display to the database. The current range of interest of the display
 * will be populated with data.
 * 
 * @param display a {@Link HasData}.
 */
public void addDataDisplay(HasData<OpInventory> display) {
    dataProvider.addDataDisplay(display);
}

/**
 * Refresh all displays.
 */
public void refreshDisplays() {
    dataProvider.refresh();
}

public static Widget init() {

    hpMain.clear();
    table.setWidth("100%");
    table.setSelectionModel(selectionModel);
    Ioma.dataservice.getPartInventory(new AsyncCallback<ArrayList<OpInventory>>() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(ArrayList<OpInventory> result) {              
            dataProvider.setList(result);
            // Attach a column sort handler to the ListDataProvider to sort the list.
            sortHandler = new ListHandler<OpInventory>(result);
            table.addColumnSortHandler(sortHandler);
            dataProvider.addDataDisplay(table);

            if (table.getColumnCount() == 0) {
                initTable();
            }               
        }
    });

    //add in table
    hpMain.add(table);
    return hpMain;
}

public static void initTable() {

    // Add a text column to show the part ID.
    Column<OpInventory, Number> partIDColumn = new Column<OpInventory, Number>(new NumberCell()) {
        @Override
        public Integer getValue(OpInventory object) {
            return object.getPartID();
        }
    };
    table.addColumn(partIDColumn, "Part ID");
    table.setColumnWidth(partIDColumn, 4, Unit.PX);

    //add a sort to partID
    partIDColumn.setSortable(true);
    sortHandler.setComparator(partIDColumn, new Comparator<OpInventory>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(OpInventory o1, OpInventory o2) {
            return Integer.valueOf(o1.getPartID()).compareTo(o2.getPartID());
        }
    });

    // Add a text column to show the part Number.
    Column<OpInventory, String> partNumberColumn = new Column<OpInventory, String>(new EditTextCell()) {
        @Override
        public String getValue(OpInventory object) {
            return object.getPartNumber();
        }
    };
    table.addColumn(partNumberColumn, "Part Number");
    table.setColumnWidth(partNumberColumn, 4, Unit.PX);

    //add a sort to the part Number
    partNumberColumn.setSortable(true);
    sortHandler.setComparator(partNumberColumn, new Comparator<OpInventory>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(OpInventory o1, OpInventory o2) {
            return o1.getPartNumber().compareTo(o2.getPartNumber());
        }
    });

    //add a field updater to be notified when the user enters a new Part Number
    partNumberColumn.setFieldUpdater(new FieldUpdater<OpInventory, String>() {
        @Override
        public void update(int index, OpInventory object, String value) {
            object.setPartNumber(value);
            //TODO add async call to database to update part Number
            table.redraw();
        }
    });

    // Add a text column to show the name.
    Column<OpInventory, String> nameColumn = new Column<OpInventory, String>(new EditTextCell()) {
        @Override
        public String getValue(OpInventory object) {
            return object.getName();
        }
    };
    table.addColumn(nameColumn, "Name");
    table.setColumnWidth(nameColumn, 10, Unit.PX);

    //add a field updater to be notified when the user enters a new part name
    nameColumn.setFieldUpdater(new FieldUpdater<OpInventory, String>() {
        @Override
        public void update(int index, OpInventory object, String value) {
            object.setName(value);
            //TODO add async call to database to update part name

            table.redraw();
        }
    });

    //add a sort to the name
    nameColumn.setSortable(true);
    sortHandler.setComparator(nameColumn, new Comparator<OpInventory>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(OpInventory o1, OpInventory o2) {
            return o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName());
        }
    });

}
```

this is the Opinventory class to hold each object in the datagrid

```
public class OpInventory implements Comparable<OpInventory>, IsSerializable {

int partID;
String partNumber;
String name;
String desc;
String partLotNumber;
String supplier;
String reOrderNumber;
boolean isActive;
int quantity;
Double price;

/**
* The key provider that provides the unique ID of a contact.
*/
public static final ProvidesKey<OpInventory> KEY_PROVIDER = new ProvidesKey<OpInventory>() {
    @Override
    public Object getKey(OpInventory item) {
        return item == null ? null : item.getPartID();
    }
};

@Override
public int compareTo(OpInventory o) {
    return (o == null || o.partNumber == null) ? -1 : -o.partNumber.compareTo(partNumber);
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (o instanceof OpInventory) {
        return partID == ((OpInventory) o).partID;
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return partID;
}

public OpInventory(int partID, String partNumber, String name, String desc, String partLotNumber, String supplier, String reOrderNumber, Double price, boolean isActive) {
    this.partID = partID;
    this.partNumber = partNumber;
    this.name = name;
    this.desc = desc;
    this.partLotNumber = partLotNumber;
    this.supplier = supplier;
    this.reOrderNumber = reOrderNumber;
    this.price = price;
    this.isActive = isActive;
}

public OpInventory() {

}

//getters and setters here
```

}

Comment: not completely sure, but the sortHandler seems to be initialized only after `table.addColumnSortHandler(sortHandler);` - i.e. you are adding `null` as sort handler.

Comment: isn't the sortHandler initialized in the previous line?

Comment: sorry, just missed it, I've just notice it in initTable().

Comment: thanks, your code helped me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently my issue was with the fact that I had a keyProvider in both classes, instead of just one. I removed it from the OpInventory class and it seems to work now. this looks like a very specific issue so I expect this question will be closed soon. but I'll leave the code there for future analysis.